# the implementations of JMS2

Tags: jms

Who knows how many implementations for JMS2.0 which is JSR343 spefic?
I'm searching a full sample to demonstrate a JMS2 application, but I'm short of this knowledge.
I hope the list of these implementations including the name, url and the beginning version supporting JMS2.

Comment: hornetq2.4+ http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html_single/index.html

Comment: see my demo for JMS2.0: https://github.com/feuyeux/quiland/tree/master/java/air-mq2

Comment: My demo came from the demo of GlassFish4 & HornetQ2.4.0. The HornetQ works well on embedded version, also you can run it on WildFly8+.